# CTRL + C doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

Please advise what should I reset to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> work back again?

CTRL + ALT + C works.

Checking the stty -a shows:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 174; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

CTRL + C doesn't work in terminal only, it do work anywhere else.

Opened a document in terminal and copied using CTRL + C and pasted back to the terminal - works.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101319/discussion-on-question-by-steves-ctrl-c-doesnt-work-in-ubuntu-18-04).